# Find the chromatic polynomial to this graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Im starting to learn graph theory and i want to learn which approaches to take when it comes to finding the chromatic polynomial to different graphs.

Say we have these graphs,

[Graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvtWe.png)

I can see that G1 is similar to k7 so using deletion-contraction to get subgraphes would be the best approach for that graph i think. But what about the G2 and G3? Does the deletion-contraction method work on those to? Or are there other approaches you can use and more importantly, how do you you know when you should use them?

Answer (score 1):

While there are other approaches to finding the chromatic polynomial, deletion/contraction is the only one that can be reasonably done by hand. Use it in all cases, because it works for *all* graphs and is simple to understand. Indeed, even mathematics software suites use deletion/contraction.

The biggest improvement you can make on the basic algorithm is to use the known explicit polynomials for special classes of graphs, like trees and cycles. The polynomial of the graph in question should be decomposed into these simpler polynomials so as to ease the work.